# Generating a single .txt file from a CSV with a text template for each user

Tags: powershell, csv, templates, text

I'm new at scripting so I would like your advices to enlighten me !

I need to generate **a single .txt** file from a .CSV shared by my colleagues.

A text template ($text) is generated for each user.

[CSV sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7eis.png)

Here is my first attempt :

```
$users = import-csv C:\temp\test_user.csv


foreach($user in $users) {

$NOM = Select-Object $user.NOM
$PRENOM = Select-Object $user.PRENOM
$PROLE = select-Object $user.PROLE
$SITE = Select-Object $user.SITE
$SERVICE = Select-Object $user.SERVICE

$text = "dn: CN=$PRENOM.$NOM,OU=SECRET,OU=Utilisateurs,DC=SECRET,DC=fr
changetype: add
objectClass: top
objectClass: syncEngineAuxObject
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn:$PRENOM.$NOM
businessCategory: DOSIP
telephoneNumber: 0153743211
displayName: $PRENOM.$NOM
PRole: $PROLE;$SITE;$SERVICE
sn: $NOM
department: DOSIP
mail: $PRENOM.$NOM@SECRET.fr
givenName: $PRENOM
sAMAccountName: $PRENOM.$NOM
title: 10
pacaffichintra: O `r`n" 

write-output $text  | add-content c:\temp\result.txt

}
```

I meet two problems.

- $NOM, $PRENOM, $PROLE, $SITE and $SERVICE are not generated in $text. I think it's because of my CSV format but I don't manage to make it work !
- If a user has already  been generated in the .txt, I'd like to only add the attributes and not generate $text again. Example in CSV SAMPLE.

What I'm trying to get :

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXxcJ.png)

Could you give me some advice ? I think I'm not using the good method :)

Sorry for my english, it's not my native language :)

Comment: Try ` | Get-Member` on your `$text` variable

Comment: First of all: A CSV-file is a text-file. You can open it in any text editor and see for yourself. In fact, you should do that, to determine which delimiter is used. Default delimiter for Import-Csv is ','. You should check that your file is using that. Also it could be good to show a few lines from the file, not a screen shot, that way it is easier to help you.

Comment: Remove the `Select-Object` cmdlet, `$NOM = $User.NOM` will do

Comment: Thank you. I removed select-object and converted my CSV and now it works !